# Tensorflow RandomContrast Layer Error "LookupError: gradient registry has no entry for: AdjustContrastv2"

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, neural-network

I get the following error when using `tf.keras.layers.RandomContrast(...)` on tensorflow 2.7.0

```
    File "/tmp/ipykernel_69350/2836335801.py", line 16, in train_step  *
        gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)

    LookupError: gradient registry has no entry for: AdjustContrastv2
```

Do I have to define a custom gradient registry as a workaround, or is there a more direct solution to this problem?

Here's the model section:

```py
def make_discriminator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"))
    model.add(layers.Rescaling(scale=2, offset=-1))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.RandomZoom(0.15))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.RandomTranslation(0.12,0.12))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.RandomContrast(0.2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Resizing(50,50))
    
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64,(5,5),strides=(2, 2),padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.SpatialDropout2D(0.2))

    ...
```

And here's the inner method in the training loop

```py
@tf.function
def train_step(images):
    noise = tf.random.normal(noise_dim)

    with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
      generated_images = generator(noise, training=True)

      real_output = discriminator(images, training=True)
      fake_output = discriminator(generated_images, training=True)

      gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_output)
      disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)

    gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
    gradients_of_discriminator = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)

    generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))
    discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, discriminator.trainable_variables))
    
    return generated_images
```

Generator Model:

```py
def make_generator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()

    model.add(layers.Dense(24*24*4, input_shape=[in_shape]))
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    
    model.add(layers.Reshape((24,24,4)))

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, (8,8), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())

    ...
    
    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(3, (8,8), strides=(4, 4), padding='same', use_bias=False, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(layers.Rescaling(scale=.5, offset=.5))
    
    return model
```

If I remove the RandomContrast layer, everything works fine.

Comment: Can you show a bit more details of your training loop and also how your `generator` model is defined?

Comment: Added the mentioned details.  Let me know if you need to see anything else.